# How to crop the sub-image using its centroid?

Tags: matlab, crop, centroid

To get a sub-image there is `imcrop` function. but I want to crop the sub-image using its `centroid`, `(x,y)` that was achieved already.

```
Image = 512x512
Centroid = (x,y) = (178.92, 207.20)
```

Also, the `imcrop` function doesn't get any input as Centroid.

```
B = imcrop(A, [col, row, width, height];
```

How to crop the sub-image using its centroid ?

Also, according to the specified size and position of the rectangle that is estimated using the center of `(x, y)`), the sub-image is cropped but its output wasn't correct.

Ex:

```
To calculate the input argument of `imcrop` function, we have:
Diam of Obj = 50 pixel. 
then its window = 50x50 pixel.
and so 57/2 = 28 to add and subtract of centroid.

Win_Obj = imcrop(RNod,[c(1)-28, c(2)-28, c(1)+28, c(2)+28]);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand: you want to cut out some part of the image but you only know 1 position? Why do you think this is possible? Please elaborate ....

Comment: @ avermaet: I don't know it is possible or not. Yes, I have only one position and it is centroid of object.

Comment: @avermaet: Yes, I have the object's information using 'regionprops' but they aren't exact (The object is a tumor)

Comment: Ok, I have no experience in processing tumor images, but can't you just add some percentage to the known object corners/edges? (to extend the croped region)

Comment: please see the cropped sub-image. The object should be in the center of window, and my problem is object corners/edges!!

Comment: What is `c` in your imcrop call?

Comment: It is the Centroid of object: (x=c(1) , y=c(2))

Comment: Try `imcrop(img, [c(1)-28 c(2)-28 2*28 2*28])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your post and also the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imcrop.html), the function `imcrop()` uses a rectangle as second parameter in the form `[x_min y_min width height]`, so you just need to change your call of `imcrop` to the following form:

```
% c is the known centroid position
Win_Obj = imcrop(RNod, [c(1)-28 c(2)-28 2*28 2*28]);
```

This should give you a sub-image with your object in the center.